# Are there two types of curve tracers?

Tags: oscilloscope

I recently discovered the device class 'curve tracer', the kind that you hook up to an oscilloscope via BNC in X-Y mode to test components.

It appears to me as if there would be two variants.

- 2 terminals for diodes, capacitors, inductors, etc. This variant draws a single trace on the screen.
- 3 terminals for transistors. this variant draws a comb-like shape on the screen, reflecting the transistor response under stimulation of various voltage levels.

Is my understanding correct?
If yes, is there a kit or device out there that combines both functionalities in a single circuit?

Comment: A 2 terminal device is a subset, so any curve tracer that can test 3 terminal devices can also test 2 terminal devices. A simple, low-voltage, low-current curve tracer isn't that difficult to make. High voltage and high current curve tracers are more difficult to create.

Comment: Yes there should be for 2 terminals CE is shorted on BCE for Y axis current*R ,  B = x axis voltage , B is a staircase sawtooth current source * Rfb, or something like that

Comment: I wonder how that works in practice. If I connect a two terminal device to the test fixture, wouldn't it try to draw a 'comb' like shape on the screen too?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is easier as a shopping question https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=transistor+curve+tracer&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-34002-13078-0&mkcid=2&keyword=transistor+curve+tracer&crlp=_1-1300-0-1-3&MT_ID=&geo_id=&rlsatarget=kwd-76759788443308%3Aloc-32&adpos=&device=c&mktype=&loc=124118&poi=&abcId=&cmpgn=329851882&sitelnk=&adgroupid=1228154640001187&network=s&matchtype=p&msclkid=65e8c3ad7cdf13c0e1be9c2514249b57&ul_noapp=true

The method you use depends on your written specs.

Yes the operating mode switches pins for sawtooth sweep and current sensing.